# unable to login to chatgpt on broswers supported by os 10.11

Tags: operating-system, openai-api, osx-elcapitan, chatgpt-api

I am on os 10.11 (el capitan) and on none of the browsers I have the chatgpt's login button does not work, as if i am not clicking on the login button, nothing happens and I am not able to use chatgpt!

I have the latest supported versions of Safari, Chrome, FireFox, Vivaldi, Opera. Is there a way (other than upgrading os or installing windows or chromeflex os!)?

Comment: You are truly lost if you think this is an appropriate site for this question.